# Angular 2, mystery with dependency injection

Tags: angular

I consider myself an ng2 expert (heavy into my 2nd application) and yet every once in a while I would run into a gotcha... and here is one

I have a simple table component called simpleGridTable:

```
<simpleGridTable #userSimpleGridTable>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th sortableHeader="name" [sort]="sort">name</th>
  <th sortableHeader="businessId" [sort]="sort">business</th>
  <th>access keys [0-7]</th>
  <th>privileges (id)</th>
  <th>privileges (name)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="simpleGridRecord" [table]="userSimpleGridTable" simpleGridRecord *ngFor="#item of m_businesses | OrderBy:sort.field:sort.desc; #index=index" [item]="item" [index]="index">
  <td style="width: 20%" simpleGridData (labelEdited)="onLabelEdited($event,'name')" editable="true" field="name" [item]="item"></td>
  <td style="width: 8%" simpleGridData field="businessId" [item]="item"></td>
  <td style="width: 20%" simpleGridDataChecks (changed)="setAccessMask($event)" [item]="item" [checkboxes]="getAccessMask(item)"></td>
  <td style="width: 12%" simpleGridData field="privilegeId" [item]="item"></td>
  <td style="width: 40%" simpleGridDataDropdown [testSelection]="selectedPriveleges()" (changed)="setPriveleges($event)" field="name" [item]="item" [dropdown]="m_priveleges"></td>
  <!-- <td simpleGridDataImage color="dodgerblue" [field]="item.getKey('studioLite') == '0' ? 'fa-circle' : 'fa-circle-o'" [item]="item"></td> -->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

inside of it I have a simpleGridRecord which you can see its directive above in:

```
<tr class="simpleGridRecord" [table]="userSimpleGridTable" simpleGridRecord *ngFor="#item of m_businesses | OrderBy:sort.field:sort.desc; #index=index" [item]="item" [index]="index">
```

the component of simpleGridRecord is as follows (and tried to dependency inject the parent SimpleGridTable:

```
import {Component, Injectable, Input, Output, ChangeDetectionStrategy, HostListener, HostBinding, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
```

import {SimpleGridTable} from "./SimpleGridTable";

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'tr[simpleGridRecord]',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      template: `
          <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class SimpleGridRecord {

    constructor(tb:SimpleGridTable){
        console.log(tb);
    }
    ....
```

and my SimpleGridTable component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'simpleGridTable',
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
providers: [SimpleGridTable],
pipes: [OrderBy],
directives: [COMMON_DIRECTIVES, SimpleGridSortableHeader, SimpleGridRecord, SimpleGridData],
styleUrls: [`../comps/simplegrid/SimpleGrid.css`],
template: `
    <table class="table simpleTable">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </table>      
`....
})
export class SimpleGridTable {
...
```

and yet the simpleGridRecord cannot seem to be able to inject its parent table as I get an error of:

[image]

I don't use @Inject as I am using TypeScript...
I do [provide] the table to its decedents

the entire class can be seen here:
https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/tree/master/src/comps/simplegrid

tx for reading

Sean

Comment: providers: [SimpleGridTable] in SimpleGridTable component? I'm guessing you misstyped that.

Comment: You're already injecting the table with the `[table]` attribute binding. Why would you want to do it using DI?  How would the injector know which parent table instance to use?

Comment: injecting the table is a workaround until I find a solution ... thus this post... regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're injecting a parent into a child, especially if the parent and child are defined in different files, you'll very likely need to wrap any reference to the parent class in the child class in a [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html), like so:

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => SimpleGridTable) tb: SimpleGridTable ){
    console.log(tb);
}
```

This is a workaround for the fact that it is impossible for the parent class to be loaded at the time the child class (which has to be loaded first) is loaded.

Also,

> I don't use @Inject as I am using TypeScript... I do [provide] the table to its decedents

Note that there are circumstances where `@Inject` is necessary in Typescript apps - this being one of them.

It also bears mentioning that I've never seen a component type included in `providers` as you've done here, and I would encourage you to verify that this is doing what you think it's doing. In any case, FWIW, what you're doing with it isn't very clear to me as a reader of your code, and IMHO using `@Inject` with constructor injection is a cleaner and more idiomatic approach to injecting parent components into their children.

Comment: WOW... TX SO MUCH... I knew about fwdRef and even used it .. but only understood it in the context of bringing forward an implementation when working within the same file and needing to change the load order of classes... I didn't think of using it in separate files to control injection order. can u explain "Note that there are circumstances where @Inject is necessary in Typescript apps - this being one of them." ?